# What does IdentityServer4 provide that I cannot get with Azure Active Directory alone?

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, token, identityserver4

We currently have Azure Active Directory with several thousand users in Active Directory. What does IdentityServer4 provide that I cannot get with connecting my .NET and/or Java apps to AAD alone?  Can AAD provide me with an auth token that can be used to access the front-end app as well as the back-end API?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by this please? "Can AAD provide me with an auth token that can be used to access the front-end app as well as the back-end API?" - Do you mean can it provide an id_token?

Comment: I need to secure my front-end app (CMS), VueJS apps contained within as well as calls to APIs, all with a single sign-on.  Seamless experience, one login and the user gets a token they can use everywhere.  I know IndentityServer can do that, but can Azure Active Directory?

Answer (score 1):

The key benefit is control (you can model your clients and resources and taylor your UX as you see fit) and the ability to use it as a federation gateway. E.g. if you need to support multiple customers many of which may want integration to their own IDP.

Comment: Would you mind going into detail with your answer? Please. I am facing the same question and try to understand your answer. Is this now the key benefit of AAD or IS4?